# WSO2 IS 5.2.0 Admin SOAP Services response time compared to WSO2 IS 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of one machine deployed on EC2 AWS instance. I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machine on which the IS is deployed is Windows Server 2012 R2.
I also have a solution which wraps the IS Admin Soap services and allows me to automate some of the processes like:
-- Service Provider creation and configuration
-- User creation and configuration
-- Tenant creation and configuration

After upgrading to WSO2 IS 5.2.0 I started experiencing delays in the responses of the admin SOAP Services. Since I am using AWS I double checked whether I am using the most appropriate region to have the IS machine. Indeed it was - I am using the Frankfurt region.

I decided to do a simple test to see whether there is delay and if so how it affect my applications. So I created a simple Console Application which was hosted on my local machine and configured the Service References first against my new DEV IS 5.2.0 machine(Frankfurt region). For my test purposes I am using RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl and I am trying to create a user. Ran the test several times and it seems that it takes about 6-7 seconds to create user.

Then I used the exact same conditions in order to run the test against DEV IS 5.0.0 machine which is also hosted in the same region (Frankfurt) and is using the exact same machine configuration (t2.large). Once again the Console Application was hosted on my local machine. The result from the second test was - 1 second to create the user using the very same admin SOAP service and the exact same logic in the Console Application under the same conditions the first test was executed.
Please find below image that displays some of the test results:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6rrhnczrutmmxw/IS5.2%20vs%20IS%205.0%20SOAP%20Service.png?dl=0

Is this a known behavior, or some sort of configuration should be applied to avoid such delays from the admin SOAP services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a configuration issue. In the following file:
"[wso2is-5.2.0_HOME]\repository\conf\identity\identity.xml"
There is a section named "EventListeners" and in there the following listener:

```
        <EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener" name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener" orderId="50" enable="true"/>
```

Once I disabled this listener, all my issues regarding the delays in the responses of the SOAP admin services disappeared.
I did basic search to see what is the purpose of this listener and was able ti find the following:
http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.bg/2016/02/account-deactivation-with-wso2-identity.html